# generalized R squared (Naglekerkes R^2)

Tags: r, statistics, regression, glm

does anybody know how to compute Naglekerkes generalized R Squared for GLMs using R? And does it makes any sence to use it for count data regression?

References:

[generalized R^2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_squared)

"Scroll down at to the bottom of this article!"

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(sos)  ## you may have to install.packages("sos") first
findFn("nagelkerke")
```

This finds functions in various packages: probably most useful are `lrm` in the `rms` package (an updated version of the `Design` package) and `NagelkerkeR2` in the `fmsb` package. Although if by "count data regression" you mean a Poisson rather than a binomial/binary model, `lrm` won't do it for you.  But the other should.

I don't see why it wouldn't apply to count data (Poisson regression) ... although there is always debate about how useful the various analogues of R<sup>2</sup> are once you get outside the realm of ordinary linear models ...